# Scrolling to end position in a list-view

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a class "**ChatListView**" which is inherited from **Listview**.

```
public  class ChatListView:ListView
{
}
```

and have made a list programatically using ChatListView in Cs :

```
 messageList = new ChatListView();
            messageList.HasUnevenRows = true;
            messageList.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            messageList.SetBinding(ChatListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Messages"));
            messageList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(CreateMessageCell);
```

I have binded this to a viewmodel where I am getting "Messages"

```
 Messages = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel>(TotalMessages.Skip(TotalMessages.Count - App.PagingCount));
```

I need to scroll the list to its end position .For which I have written code as follow:

```
 ViewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += (s, ex) =>
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (ViewModel.Messages.Any())
                {
                    messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);

                }
            });
        };
```

But This just doesn't work for me. I feel there would be a problem in List call or List name. Any guidance or help can help me find what is wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of swapping out the `Messages` instance every time you get new messages, you should simply add to it. Otherwise your entire `ListView` will refresh and the `CollectionChanged` event won't fire, because it is an entirely new instance.

So when you receive messages do:

```cs
Messages.Add(newMessage);
```

Then the `CollectionChanged` event will fire the `Added` event:

```cs
ViewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add) // items were added
    {
        messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
    }
}
```

Make sure to instantiate `Messages` in your constructor or as part of the property declaration.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel> Messages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel>();
```

Comment: Yes. I added  to messages like this ->TotalMessages.Add(chatMessage);
Messages are only those 20 messages from Total Messages. and I tried to use your suggested way, But it seems **"ViewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;"** is not accessible .So I used.....  private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action.Equals(CollectionChangeAction.Add))
            {
                messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
            }
        }
But no luck

Comment: I think may be i am not calling Listview properly .Just a gut feeling . Can you help me check if its correct or not .

Answer (score 1):

Try to change ScrollToPosition.End to ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible

Comment: Hey thanks for replying , I did that but No Success.

Comment: If you run Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread outside from CollectionChanged it is working ?

Comment: Sadly no . Its simply not working . I have kept in constructor , On Appearing . But no success

Comment: Can you check accepted answer here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60811/listview-any-way-to-mvvm-bind-to-scrollto

Comment: I tried , Still nothing. I am wondering issue is something else .May be will calling list. :/

Comment: I dont know ... last chance https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/28/28277/bug.html#c8

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. this worked for me.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                }
                else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                {
                    messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, true);
                }
```

Comment: check you OnCollectionChanged is triggering when new message is coming and its having the messages.

Comment: Check this for iOS ----        messageList.ScrollTo(ViewModel.Messages[ViewModel.Messages.Count-1], ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);

Comment: I want for android mainly

Comment: Thanks . I find out what was error , My calling was not correct . Thanks for your help :)